# Set local notification for 1 day before or 2 day before swift 3

Tags: swift3, calendar, localnotification

I want to add local notification in my app. I am filling information in `textfields` and set `date`, `time and reminder` before particular date selected for the exam. Anyone implement such a demo then please suggest me what to do.

Comment: watch this    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnvqLqoG4JM

Answer (score 1):

Answer is based on what ever i understood,  Please change the time and reminder string as per your requirement.

```
 func scheduleNotification(InputUser:String) {

let now: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: NSDate())

let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let date = cal.dateBySettingHour(now.hour, minute: now.minute + 1, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())
let reminder = UILocalNotification()
reminder.fireDate = date
reminder.alertBody = InputUser
reminder.alertAction = "Cool"
reminder.soundName = "sound.aif"
reminder.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute




UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminder)

print("Firing at \(now.hour):\(now.minute+1)")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set up Daily basic Local Notification 1 Day before or you can be modified it with the help of specific date in **Swift 3.1**

---

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

fileprivate struct AlarmKey{
    static let startWorkIdentifier = "com.Reminder.Notification" //Add your own Identifier for Local Notification
    static let startWork = "Ready for work? Toggle To \"Available\"."
}


class AlarmManager: NSObject{

    static let sharedInstance = AlarmManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    //MARK: - Clear All Previous Notifications
    func clearAllNotifications(){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        }
    }

    func addReminder(with _ hour: Int, minutes: Int){
        clearAllNotifications()

        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.hour = hour // example - 7 Change you time here Progrmatically
        dateComponent.minute = minutes // example - 00 Change you time here Progrmatically


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            dateComponent.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent

            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: false) //Set here **Repeat** condition

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.body = AlarmKey.startWork //Message Body
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

            let notification = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: AlarmKey.startWorkIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notification) {(error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            //iOS *9.4 below if fails the Above Condition....
            dateComponent.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
            let calender = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
            let date = calender.date(from: dateComponent)!
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.fireDate = date
            localNotification.alertBody = AlarmKey.startWork
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
//This is optional method if you want to show your Notification foreground condition
extension AlarmManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void){
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
    }
}
```